# How can i solve the Null Pointer Exception i cant get anything on my fragment

Tags: java, android

The activity below is a tabbed activity attached to the fragment below and I want to pass the "Data" variable from the response to the fragment below so that I can get the value inside it and render it to the view . Help me with the code to do that.

This is the Activity I want to send data from

```
public class ViewProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
    String Name;
    Api api;
    String token;
    Bundle bundle;
    MyProfile fragobj;
    String Date_of_Birth;
    Data data;
    ImageView backbtn;
    MyProfileViewModel myProfileViewModel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_profile);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        backbtn = findViewById(R.id.back_button_viewprofile);
        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), drawerLayout.class));
            }
        });
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        token = Utility.fetchFromSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(),"user_access_token");


        getUserDetails();


    }
    public void getUserDetails() {
        api = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(Api.class);
        Call<ProfileInformationResponse> call = api.getProfileInformation("Bearer " + token);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProfileInformationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProfileInformationResponse> call, Response<ProfileInformationResponse> response) {
                ProfileInformationResponse result = response.body();
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Membermessage membermessage = result.getMembermessage();
                     data = membermessage.getData();
                    Name = data.getName();
                    Log.e("The Name :",Name);
                    Utility.updateSharedPreference(getApplicationContext(), "Name",Name);
                    String ID_No = data.getIDNo();
                    myProfileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(ViewProfile.this).get(MyProfileViewModel.class);
                    myProfileViewModel.init();
                    myProfileViewModel.sendData(data);


                  Date_of_Birth = data.getDateOfBirth();

                    String Address = data.getAddress();

                    String City = data.getCity();

                    String Mobile_No = data.getMobilePhoneNo();

                    String E_Mail = data.getEMail();






                    //for the next of kin
                    NextOfKinmessage nextOfKinmessage  = result.getNextOfKinmessage();
                    List<Datum> datumList = nextOfKinmessage.getData();
                    Datum datum = datumList.get(0);
                    String name = datum.getName();

                    Log.e("The nxtName", name);
                    String relationship = datum.getRelationship();

                    String   percent_allocation = datum.getPercentAllocation().toString();

                    String Date_Birth = datum.getDateOfBirth();

                    String adress = datum.getAddress();

                    String mail = datum.getEmail();



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProfileInformationResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        private final Context mContext;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case  0:
                    return new MyProfile();

                case 1 :
                    return  new Nextofkin();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case  0:
                    return "My Profile";
                case 1:
                    return  "Next Of Kin";
                default:
                    return  null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

My Viewmodel is this below

```
public class MyProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<Data> dataMutableLiveData;
    public void init(){
        dataMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    public void sendData(Data data){
        dataMutableLiveData.setValue(data);

    }
    public LiveData<Data> getData(){
        return dataMutableLiveData;
    }
}
```

This is my fragment where I want the Data from

```
public class MyProfile extends Fragment {
    TextView names,idno,dob, address,city,mobileno,emailno,memberno;
    String token   , Name ;
    Context thiscontext;
    Api api;
    MyProfileViewModel myProfileViewModel;
    public MyProfile(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {




        thiscontext = container.getContext();

       // Log.e("Name :" ,String.valueOf(name));
        token = Utility.fetchFromSharedPreference(thiscontext,"user_access_token");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_profile, container, false);
        names= root.findViewById(R.id.names);
        idno= root.findViewById(R.id.id_number);
        dob= root.findViewById(R.id.Date_of_Birth);
        address= root.findViewById(R.id.AddressPROFILE);
        city= root.findViewById(R.id.City);
        mobileno= root.findViewById(R.id.Mobile_Phone_NoPROFILE);
        emailno= root.findViewById(R.id.EmailP);
        memberno= root.findViewById(R.id.Member_TypeP);


        return root;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        myProfileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity() ).get(MyProfileViewModel.class);
       LiveData<Data> data = myProfileViewModel.getData();
       Log.e("Data sent", String.valueOf(data));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Tony, it looks like since the getUserDetails is Async, maybe when the fragment is added, the getUserDetails Response isn't prepared yet, hence, the user data is not assigned to the viewmodel, and when accessing it, it was still empty, please set logs in the response and compare it with the time of  the "Data sent" log.

Comment: you are right how can i then solve it

Comment: you can try the approach mentioned by Manuel in the answers section, get data ( and for better UX show a loader) then prepare the viewpager and its adapter, that way the data will always be ready, and in case of error you will show a toast/ snackbar with a certain message to notify the user of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach is the next:
1. When you are fetching data, then show a progress bar
2. If the result is ok, then init the viewpager to show the data
3. If you have an error, notify or handle it

But, with your approach, the solution could be the next:
First, share your viewmodel to communicate the activity with the fragment
And second, in your success method notify to your viewmodel the data result.  Next, the viewmodel must be to update the appropriate livedata that must be to observed by the fragment.

Comment: how can i implement your way am having a hard time

Comment: something like this:  Your activity fetch the data, when the result is success, then populate your viewpager and notify to the viewmodel the result, you need a method that receive your param.  In the ViewModel, your method that receive the result, pass the value to the livedata yourMutableLiveData.postValue(dataResult).  And your fragment observe your viewmodel, yourViewModel.yourLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { // here you have your data, so update your UI })

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `myProfileViewModel` in the `oncreate` method of `ViewProfile` activity. Then just observe the `LiveData` in the required fragment.

Comment: i have done that i still get a null reference from my fragment